# URI in RESTful architecture

Tags: uri, restful-architecture

I am confused here! I read a blog and it said in RESTful architecture,we can use more than one URI to represent a resource.

Is this right,since URI is use as identifier,it should be unique. Did I misunderstand something?

Sorry I am not going to post the link of that post because it is written in Chinese:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is true. REST follows existing standards (aka. uniform interface constraint), now we are talking about the URI standard.

I think the simplest example about this is localhost. So imagine you have a REST service on `http://localhost/api` on your computer. Now by default you can reach the same service using `http://127.0.0.1/api`. So even the api root does not have an 1:1 relationship with the URIs in this case. In terms of the URI standard uniqueness means an 1:n relation between the resource and the URIs. This is different to the uniqueness term you are used to by relational databases. So in different words, a single resource can be identified by multiple URIs, but a single URI can identify only a single resource.